# changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "No package matching 'monit' is available

Tags: gnu, ansible

tengo un problema al tratar de instalar "monit" con un playbook de ansible

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: "Install monit if not present"
    apt:
      name: "monit"
      state: present
```

Ese es mi playbook y el error que me devuelve es:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "No package matching 'monit' is available"}
```

¿Sabéis alguna solución a este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que tengas que actualizar la caché de paquetes primero y luego instalar. Probá lo siguiente:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: "Install monit if not present"
      apt:
        name: "monit"
        update_cache: true
        state: present
```